# Universal test for Admin privileges

Tags: powershell

Is there a single guaranteed method to test if the current user has admin rights? I have tried this

```
$isAdmin = (new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole("Administrators")
```

And it works, as long as Windows was originally installed in English. If Windows is installed in Spanish you have to test for Administra**d**ors. And there are a few other languages that work similarly.
My first thought is to just test for all the possible spellings, but if there is something simple, elegant and foolproof, that would be my preference.

Answer (score 6):

You are calling the `String` definition of the `IsInRole` Method, and this is why you have problems in different languages.

If you will look at the `IsInRole` OverLoadDefinitions you'll see that the first Defintion is a `String` which is the definition you are calling in your code

```
OverloadDefinitions
-------------------
bool IsInRole(string role)
bool IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole role)
bool IsInRole(int rid)
bool IsInRole(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier sid)
bool IPrincipal.IsInRole(string role)
```

This string-based overload shares the same disadvantage of the `NET LOCALGROUP Administrators` command, it relies on group names which are not the same in different OS Languages.

To solve this problem, use the `System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole` OverLoadDefinition:

```
$role = [System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole]::Administrator
```

And check against this role instead:

```
$isAdmin = (new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole($role)
```

This way you don't need to care about differrent OS languages

*To get all the available WindowsBuiltInRoles:

```
[System.Enum]::GetValues([System.Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the SID for Administrators as it's a [well-known SID](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/243330) (static).

> SID: **S-1-5-32-544**
>
> Name: Administrators
>
> Description: A built-in group. After the initial installation of the operatingsystem, the only member of the group is the Administrator account. When a computer joins a domain, the Domain Admins group is added to the Administrators group. When a server becomes a domain controller, the Enterprise Admins group also is added to the Administrators group.

```
$isAdmin = (new-object System.Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent())).IsInRole(([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]"S-1-5-32-544"))
```

Comment: Frode, that's returning false for me, both for Run As Administrator and simply double clicking the shortcut to my test script. Testing on Windows 7 Home, if that could have an impact.

Comment: Got the same error in PS2.0 in Win10. PS 5.0 casted the SID-value (string) to a SID-object auto. In PS 2.0 I had to do this manually. The updated answer should work.

Comment: As an alternative you could use WMI for resolving the SID to the group name: `([wmi]"Win32_Sid.SID='S-1-5-32-544'").AccountName`.

Comment: Interestingly, while all these approaches do test if the user account is an Admin account, they don't seem to validate if in fact full admin rights are applied. As in, sometimes without doing a right click Run as Administrator Powershell is not able to do things like file manipulation in Program Files.

Comment: I'm testing my answer as we speak using a account in the local Administrators group. Open powershell normally: False. Open powershell using Run as admin: True.  I've been using this technique in my script for years without problems.

Comment: @Gordon sure that they check if your current session is running with admin privileges, that's exactly what it does